# dplyr::rename_at gives error "must evaluate to column positions or names"

Tags: r, dplyr

I feel like I'm missing something pretty basic, but I'm having trouble using `rename_at` with a custom renamer function:

```r
library(tidyverse)
```

Say I want to swap the `Sepal` and the metric for the columns with names starting with `Sepal`. I would expect this to work, but it doesn't:

```r
iris %>%
  rename_at(vars(starts_with("Sepal"), funs(str_replace(., "(Sepal)\\.(.*)", "\\2\\.\\1"))))
#> Warning: 'glue::collapse' is deprecated.
#> Use 'glue_collapse' instead.
#> See help("Deprecated") and help("glue-deprecated").
#> Error: `funs(str_replace(., "(Sepal)\\.(.*)", "\\2\\.\\1"))` must evaluate to column positions or names, not a list
```

Nor does it work if I wrap the function call and don't use `funs()`:

```r
sepal_renamer <- function(names){
  str_replace(names, "(Sepal)\\.(.*)", "\\2\\.\\1")
}
iris %>%
  rename_at(vars(starts_with("Sepal"), sepal_renamer))
#> Warning: 'glue::collapse' is deprecated.
#> Use 'glue_collapse' instead.
#> See help("Deprecated") and help("glue-deprecated").
#> Error: `sepal_renamer` must evaluate to column positions or names, not a function
```

I know I can just use the regex powers to get the desired result, but I don't understand why it works for `rename_all` (and even `colnames<-()`) but not `rename_at`. And I'd like a solution even if making the right replacements with regex would not be possible (like trying to map some names to new names)

```r
iris %>% rename_all(funs(str_replace(., "(Sepal)\\.(.*)", "\\2\\.\\1"))) %>% colnames
#> [1] "Length.Sepal" "Width.Sepal"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width" 
#> [5] "Species"

iris %>% `colnames<-`(str_replace(colnames(.), "(Sepal)\\.(.*)", "\\2\\.\\1")) %>% colnames
#> [1] "Length.Sepal" "Width.Sepal"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width" 
#> [5] "Species"
```

Anyone have any suggestions - am I missing some basic syntax thing? The error doesn't pop anything intuitive at me, and I am more confused because it works with `rename_all` anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've got misplaced parenthesis. A closing `)` is misplaced for your `vars()` function:

```
iris %>%
  rename_at(vars(starts_with("Sepal")), ~str_replace(., "(Sepal)\\.(.*)", "\\2\\.\\1")) %>% 
  head(2)

  Length.Sepal Width.Sepal Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

Comment: Doh, of course!